# Is it possible to execute the two update queries in phpmyadmin together?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to execute the two update queries in phpmyadmin together?

Like wise

```
UPDATE jos_menu SET home = 0 WHERE 1;
UPDATE jos_menu SET home = 1 WHERE id = 9;
```

Now can we copy both these queries together and Run it on phpmyadmin sql query panel?
will it be executed?

Comment: did you try? or are you afraid?

Comment: :-) afraid.. I cant do it... on the DB its live

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, both queries will be executed. The only additional thing you might add is [transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/commit.html). Thanks to that you'll be sure that both queries executed successful:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE jos_menu SET home = 0 WHERE 1;
UPDATE jos_menu SET home = 1 WHERE id = 9;
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
update jos_menu set home=case id when 9 then 1 else 0 end
```

this will update all rows, setting 1 to all that have id=9, and 0 to the rest

Answer (score 0):

If you're not sure if some SQL will break your live site and you don't have a dev server, make a copy of the DB table and test it on that.

```
CREATE TABLE jos_menu_test LIKE jos_menu;
INSERT jos_menu_test SELECT * FROM jos_menu;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @crozin answer I did following queries:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT id into @idTech FROM `team` WHERE abbr = 'D19';
delete from team_dayoff where team_id = @idTech;
delete from team_layer_lease where team_id = @idTech;
delete from team_product_linker where team_id = @idTech;
delete from team where id = @idTech;
COMMIT;
```